# check if record exist in the table with if statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql

my bus table is empty and I am trying to check whether records exist but the program retrieve always true and jump into the true statement?! I have already tried it with `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bus` I have the same problem.

```
boolean records = stt.execute("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM bus) ");
if (records) {
    //It is always jumping here.
    return insertRecord(mac, route, latD, longD, status, con);

} else {
    // The table exist without records.
    stt.execute("ALTER TABLE bus AUTO_INCREMENT = 1");
    return insertRecord(mac, route, latD, longD, status, con);
}
```

**Edit**
I am getting this error but if I delete the lines everything works.

> Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] in context with path [/serverSide] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

```
PreparedStatement recordPrep = con
        .prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM bus");
ResultSet rs = recordPrep.getResultSet();

 if (rs.next()) {

    return insertRecord(mac, route, latD, longD, status, con);

 } else {
    // The table exist without records.
    stt.execute("ALTER TABLE bus AUTO_INCREMENT = 1");
    return insertRecord(mac, route, latD, longD, status, con);
}
```

Comment: Use `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM bus` and get the result from `ResultSet#getInt`. Use the result to check if the table is empty (0) or if it has data (> 0).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: I have tried it and I am getting the error `error Column route not found`  since the table is empty and I have column with `route` name

Answer (score 0):

The [`execute(String)` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute-java.lang.String-) doesn't return the `boolean` value of the first row, it tells you if there are rows.

> The execute method executes an SQL statement and indicates the form of the first result. You must then use the methods getResultSet or getUpdateCount to retrieve the result, and getMoreResults to move to any subsequent result(s).
>
> Returns:
>
> true if the first result is a ResultSet object; false if it is an update count or there are no results

Instead, get the `ResultSet` from the `Statement` with `getResultSet`, and check the first value of the first row, if it exists.

Comment: I have tried your solution and I am getting somthing from jersey ` Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] in context with path [/serverSide] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause` but I I delete the line it works

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM bus` if you want to check if there are any records in the `bus` table (assuming you have an `id` column, if not replace the column name with the one you have for ID, or any other column)

Comment: You should not directly use the result of `execute`, check this link for examples of how to use the mysql support: http://zetcode.com/db/mysqljava/